# Prism 4 API documentation

Tags: c#, prism

Im looking for online API documentation for the Prism framework (prism 4). Does it A) Exist? and B) if so, where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Desktop class library** 
   [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism(v=pandp.40)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism%28v=pandp.40%29)
- **Phone** 
  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj569715(v=pandp.39).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj569715%28v=pandp.39%29.aspx)
- **Silverlight** 
   [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.mefextensions.modularity(v=pandp.38)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.mefextensions.modularity%28v=pandp.38%29)

All under the [Prism 4.1 - Developer Guide to Microsoft Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140) (last 3 links on navigation).

On review, all the API docs looks somewhat incomplete compared to the [Prism 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921203) docs but I believe these are the only sources of API docs available.

Answer (score -2):

http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/55580

Comment: Yes i found that, doesnt seem to have the API in it though. Im looking for something in a similar styleto C# API docs, although im prepared to concede it wont be anything like as comprehensive